# Unknown error (-41) - file transfer using vpn

Tags: macos, vpn

Well, the following error occurs every time I try to copy a file from the university's file server when I use a VPN connection. That happens since the update to Yoseminte a few days ago, didn't occurred on Mavericks.

"Task could not be completed due to an unknown error (-41)"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this on upgrade to Yosemite. For us it was fixed by deleting the VPN service from Network Preference and putting it in fresh with all the same details. I assume it flushes some corrupt cache or something.